# Issues with Dz77BH-55K Motherboard and i7 processor on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, intel

I just built a computer with Intel's DZ77BH-55K motherboard with i7-3770 processor.

On 12.04, 11.10, and 11.04 and Linux Mint 12, the computer has been really laggy. The graphics aren't working (choppy effects, bad resolution) and the keyboard and mouse inputs are even laggy and unreliable (skips keystrokes). I'm not sure what the problem is or what I can do to fix it.

I tried `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` but nothing changed. I've also messed around in the BIOS but no luck there either.

Any ideas? Could it possibly be a hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error message during boot about turning on irqpoll, it's the firewire port.

You should disable firewire in the BIOS and it will run like a champ.